# Stop Kafka consumer when no more messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to sync my database with Kafka before exposing API endpoints. I’m using C# kafka client. Is there a way to find out if kafka is out of messages?

IsPartitionEOF doesn’t work because I can have n partitions.

Comment: Maybe by setting a timeout at the consumer connection?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to track N IsPartitionEOF events for each partition. You can identify the partition value from each consumed record.

However, if you have producers that are writing data faster than your consumer can read it, it's unlikely you'll event hit the end of the partitions, so this might not be the best design.

Comment: What if I have multiple consumers consuming different partitions?

Comment: Sure, that is the expectation. You still need to track them all.