# How to stop a Kafka consumer when no new messages are in the topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Does anyone have any good suggestions for stopping a Kafka consumer automatically when no new messages are detected in the topic? I want my application to break out of the consumer and do something else once all messages are consumed. A python solution will be much appreciated.

----------------Update----------------

I think I have fixed my problem. Here is some code that I came up with to break out of a consumer once it has read all messages in a topic. The logic is that if the consumer reads 10 `None` messages in a row, it will break. That number could be 20, 100, 1000, whatever you want it to be.

```py
x = 0
y = 0
while True:
    if y == 10:
        print(y, 'messages returned with None value. Stopping consumer.')
        break
    else:
        msg = consumer.poll(1.0)
        if msg is None:
            y += 1
            print(msg)
            print(y, 'messages with None value.')
        else:
            x += 1
            y = 0
            print(x, 'messages with values consumed.')
```

- Please note, I am using `confluent_kafka` library

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71923145/stop-kafka-consumer-when-no-more-messages

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer of the first comment, are you guaranteed the producers aren't sending data faster than your consumer? What happens when you "stop reading", but then a producer sends just one more record? If either of these are a problem, then you should rethink your design. For example, maybe you should use Kafka Connect to always dump the topic to a database, then Python can query the database as it needs to, without actually waiting on its own to consume from the topic

Comment: Please see updated post above which now includes code sample @AmilaSenadheera

Answer (score 0):

This is not something a rocket science involved here. Basically, a KAFKA Consumer will be instantiated during your consumer application start up and from there your consumer object is going to poll records frequently based on the value set in MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, the value can be ms, mins, hrs etc, but your consumer thread would be keep running and active for the next polling. If not, then your consumer instance will be declared as dead and eventually kicked out of your consumer group.

You can flip you design. For example, first execute your **something else** job, for example you want to poll a file and make a pointer when you want to poll events from the topic. In that point, execute consumer.subscribe() and keep polling data and once done, you have to call consumer.unsubscribe() and consumer.close(), and the cycle continues. Because, it is ideal when to subscribe() and unsubscribe() to your topic to make your consumer work seamlessly. Doesn't matter which techstack you use.